# Test case failing randomly while building Selenium automation in jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run jenkins job for my automation. Here I am using cucumber Bdd. While running locally in single thread, test cases are working good. But while building the job in jenkins using multiThreading, test cases are failing randomly. Once one is passed , in the successive build it is getting failed. Most of them are having the below error. It seems like there is some server issue that page is not loading in the browser while running the test cases. Can you suggest any way out to run this successfully?
My whole test cases are so large in size that if not run in multiThread it will take 6 to 7 hrs . The server is not supporting such long time. It is getting socket timeout after half of the run(after 3 hrs.)

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Course wasn't loaded after 30
>   seconds.  Build info:
>   version:'2.53.1',revision:'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d',time:
>   '2016-06-30 19:26:09' System info: host: 'jenkins-50a5c8e3',
>   ip:'100.64.111.138',os.name:'Linux',os.arch:'amd64',os.version:'2.6.32-5-xen-amd64',java.version:'1.8.0_40'Driver
>   info:driver.version:unknown

Comment: Please share more info, this means nothing.

Comment: Refer Post:http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague so the best I can do is give a vague answer of what you might want to look into.

1. **Make sure your tests can run in isolation** You mentioned it works in a single thread. If your tests don't each have isolated data (course, user, whatever) then it's really easy to have one test do something like remove a course while another test is trying to access it if you run them in parallel.
2. **Timing issues** If you have timing issues in your tests, you probably need more robust explicit waits.
3. **Make sure you properly dispose of your driver** Preferably in a finally block. You need to make sure that no matter what path your tests take, the driver will get closed. You might want to start a strategy as well to clean up stranded driver instances, restart nodes, etc...